# vim selections second number relative to first number

Tags: vim

In vim, when doing a range selection, is it possible to specify the second number in relation to the first?

For example, I know I can use a range such as this to yank line 313 to 316 inclusive:

```
:313,316y
```

but is it possible to say "yank line 313 **and the 3 lines after it**"? In other words, is there something I can replace line number 316 with that will in effect say "and the 3 lines after it"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you need to use the **`;`** instead of `,` when specifying **[`[range]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-ranges)** in order to **refer to the first part of the range and not the current line**.

1. `:313;+3y`

This command yank these lines N°: `313`, `313+1`, `313+2`, `313+3`.

2. `:313,+3y`

This one yank from line `313` to line `.+3`:  (where **`.`** is the current line N° where cursor is ) and if `.+3` < `313` it will warn you to reverse range.

Comment: awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 3):

The `yank` operation supports an optional count, so you can repeat the number of lines yanked after a starting point:

```
:313y 3
```

You can see the docs using `:help range`, it has much more detailed information on all the available options.